# Why JQuery not Working in blade templates Laravel?

Tags: jquery

My code after @endsection is like,

```
.
.
.
.

@endsection
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert();
    });
</script>
```

And its show error display below :::

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Are you include JS library ?

Comment: Yes, i'll already add it into **app.blade.php**